# Mac closes all apps randomly

Tags: macos

Since yesterday my Macbook Pro 13 (mid 2014, i7 16gb ram, 512gb) closes all running apps randomly every few minutes.
Also wifi gets disconnected momentarily - it's as if I would just log in to the system. Once I relaunch Chrome it says it's not been properly shut.

I updated to Big Sur but it didn't help.

I tried to monitor system resources but I don't see any spike before apps closing.
I have 10GB ram unused and it still happens.

Any help appreciated.

Edit - here is system log from around the time it last happend:

```
    Mar  1 16:44:14 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.suggestd): Skipping remaining event endpoints for importance boosting.
Mar  1 16:44:14 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.suggestd): Skipping remaining instance endpoints for importance boosting.
Mar  1 16:44:15 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.assistant_service[30180]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by kill[32368]
Mar  1 16:44:15 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.followupd[30184]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by kill[32369]
Mar  1 16:44:15 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.studentd[30190]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by kill[32370]
Mar  1 16:44:15 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.progressd[30196]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by kill[32372]
Mar  1 16:44:15 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.storeaccountd[30198]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by kill[32373]
Mar  1 16:44:15 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.metadata.mdwrite[30199]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by kill[32374]
Mar  1 16:44:15 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CharacterPicker.FileService[30219]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by kill[32378]
Mar  1 16:44:15 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.photoanalysisd[30271]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by kill[32382]
Mar  1 16:44:15 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.scopedbookmarksagent.xpc[30272]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by kill[32383]
Mar  1 16:44:15 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mediaanalysisd[30273]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by kill[32384]
Mar  1 16:44:15 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.amsengagementd[30391]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by kill[32386]
Mar  1 16:44:15 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.avatarsd[30392]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by kill[32387]
Mar  1 16:44:15 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (application.com.docker.docker.8730442480.8730442489[30976]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by kill[32391]
Mar  1 16:44:15 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.loginitemregisterd[30989]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by kill[32393]
Mar  1 16:44:16 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw backgroundtaskmanagementagent[32461]: objc[32461]: Class BTMLoginItem is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackgroundTaskManagement.framework/Versions/A/BackgroundTaskManagement and /System/Library/CoreServices/backgroundtaskmanagementagent. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:16 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw backgroundtaskmanagementagent[32461]: objc[32461]: Class BTMBackgroundItem is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackgroundTaskManagement.framework/Versions/A/BackgroundTaskManagement and /System/Library/CoreServices/backgroundtaskmanagementagent. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:16 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw UserEventAgent[32064]: objc[32064]: Class SPLog is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy (0x7fff8a1a9928) and /System/Library/UserEventPlugins/SystemPolicyEvents.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SystemPolicyEvents (0x10fdd9350). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:16 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw CommCenter[32472]: objc[32472]: Class CTCellularPlanManagerCameraScanAction is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Versions/A/CoreTelephony (0x7fff886d7c80) and /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Support/CommCenter (0x1074d80f8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:16 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw CommCenter[32472]: objc[32472]: Class CTSimLabel is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Versions/A/CoreTelephony (0x7fff886d6380) and /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Support/CommCenter (0x1074d9318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:18 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.10000000-0700-0000-0000-000000000000[31683]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[100]
Mar  1 16:44:18 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.07000000-0200-0000-0000-000000000000[31690]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[100]
Mar  1 16:44:18 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.0F000000-0400-0000-0000-000000000000[31684]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[100]
Mar  1 16:44:19 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.06000000-0500-0000-0000-000000000000[31685]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[100]
Mar  1 16:44:19 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.08000000-0500-0000-0000-000000000000[31682]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[100]
Mar  1 16:44:22 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: Coalition Cache Hit: app<application.com.apple.Console.1152921500311974274.1152921500311974279(501)> [5978]
Mar  1 16:44:24 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw remindd[32697]: objc[32697]: Class REMCDChangeTrackingState is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ReminderKit.framework/Versions/A/ReminderKit and /usr/libexec/remindd. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:25 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.01000000-0100-0000-0000-000000000000[31691]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[100]
Mar  1 16:44:26 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent[32698]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by kill[32782]
Mar  1 16:44:26 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent): Service only ran for 1 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 9 seconds.
Mar  1 16:44:32 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.ssh-agent[29894]): Service exited with abnormal code: 2
Mar  1 16:44:33 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw MTLCompilerService[33326]: getattrlist failed for /Library/GPUBundles/AppleIntelGraphicsShared.bundle/Contents/Resources/runtime.igil64.split: #2: No such file or directory
Mar  1 16:44:33 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw MTLCompilerService[33333]: getattrlist failed for /Library/GPUBundles/AppleIntelGraphicsShared.bundle/Contents/Resources/runtime.igil64.split: #2: No such file or directory
Mar  1 16:44:40 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPDevicesAgent[33726]: objc[33726]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x7fff8ae2aa30) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x10ae2c8c0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:40 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPDevicesAgent[33726]: objc[33726]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x7fff8ae2aa80) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x10ae2c910). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:40 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPDevicesAgent[33726]: objc[33726]: Class RPStream is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EmbeddedOSInstall.framework/Versions/A/EmbeddedOSInstall (0x7fff8a4fb360) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x10ae2c960). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:40 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPDevicesAgent[33726]: objc[33726]: Class PDFToRasterImageRef is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPLibrary.framework/Versions/A/AMPLibrary (0x7fff8a5e0648) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPDevices.framework/Versions/A/Support/AMPDevicesAgent (0x10a9e8c80). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:40 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPDevicesAgent[33726]: objc[33726]: Class AMPArtworkSourceInfo is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPLibrary.framework/Versions/A/AMPLibrary (0x7fff88782310) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPDevices.framework/Versions/A/Support/AMPDevicesAgent (0x10a9e8d98). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:40 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPDevicesAgent[33726]: objc[33726]: Class AMPLibraryClientEventsXPCObject is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPLibrary.framework/Versions/A/AMPLibrary (0x7fff88782388) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPDevices.framework/Versions/A/Support/AMPDevicesAgent (0x10a9e8e10). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:40 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPDevicesAgent[33726]: objc[33726]: Class AMPLClient is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPLibrary.framework/Versions/A/AMPLibrary (0x7fff887823b0) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPDevices.framework/Versions/A/Support/AMPDevicesAgent (0x10a9e8e38). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:40 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPDevicesAgent[33726]: objc[33726]: Class AMPLFrameworkClient is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPLibrary.framework/Versions/A/AMPLibrary (0x7fff8a5e0580) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPDevices.framework/Versions/A/Support/AMPDevicesAgent (0x10a9e8e88). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:40 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPDevicesAgent[33726]: objc[33726]: Class AMPLMediaAppClient is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPLibrary.framework/Versions/A/AMPLibrary (0x7fff88782400) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPDevices.framework/Versions/A/Support/AMPDevicesAgent (0x10a9e8ed8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:40 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPDevicesAgent[33726]: objc[33726]: Class AMPLSharingClient is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPLibrary.framework/Versions/A/AMPLibrary (0x7fff8a5e05d0) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPDevices.framework/Versions/A/Support/AMPDevicesAgent (0x10a9e8f28). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:40 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPDevicesAgent[33726]: objc[33726]: Class asn1ReceiptToken is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore (0x7fff88805a60) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreFP.framework/CoreFP (0x111fa1d90). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:40 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPDevicesAgent[33726]: objc[33726]: Class ISPurchaseReceipt is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore (0x7fff888059e8) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreFP.framework/CoreFP (0x111fa1de0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:40 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPDevicesAgent[33726]: objc[33726]: Class asn1Token is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore (0x7fff88805ad8) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreFP.framework/CoreFP (0x111fa1e30). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:40 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPDevicesAgent[33726]: objc[33726]: Class asn1SetToken is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore (0x7fff88805ab0) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreFP.framework/CoreFP (0x111fa1e58). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:40 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPDevicesAgent[33726]: objc[33726]: Class asn1SequenceToken is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore (0x7fff88805a88) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreFP.framework/CoreFP (0x111fa1e80). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:40 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPDevicesAgent[33726]: objc[33726]: Class asn1IntegerToken is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore (0x7fff88805a10) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreFP.framework/CoreFP (0x111fa1ea8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:40 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPDevicesAgent[33726]: objc[33726]: Class asn1OSToken is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore (0x7fff88805a38) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreFP.framework/CoreFP (0x111fa1ed0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:41 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPLibraryAgent[33727]: objc[33727]: Class PDFToRasterImageRef is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPLibrary.framework/Versions/A/AMPLibrary and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPLibrary.framework/Versions/A/Support/AMPLibraryAgent. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:41 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPLibraryAgent[33727]: objc[33727]: Class asn1ReceiptToken is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore (0x7fff88805a60) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreFP.framework/Versions/A/CoreFP (0x10d804d90). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:41 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPLibraryAgent[33727]: objc[33727]: Class ISPurchaseReceipt is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore (0x7fff888059e8) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreFP.framework/Versions/A/CoreFP (0x10d804de0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:41 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPLibraryAgent[33727]: objc[33727]: Class asn1Token is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore (0x7fff88805ad8) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreFP.framework/Versions/A/CoreFP (0x10d804e30). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:41 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPLibraryAgent[33727]: objc[33727]: Class asn1SetToken is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore (0x7fff88805ab0) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreFP.framework/Versions/A/CoreFP (0x10d804e58). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:41 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPLibraryAgent[33727]: objc[33727]: Class asn1SequenceToken is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore (0x7fff88805a88) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreFP.framework/Versions/A/CoreFP (0x10d804e80). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:41 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPLibraryAgent[33727]: objc[33727]: Class asn1IntegerToken is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore (0x7fff88805a10) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreFP.framework/Versions/A/CoreFP (0x10d804ea8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:41 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPLibraryAgent[33727]: objc[33727]: Class asn1OSToken is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore (0x7fff88805a38) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreFP.framework/Versions/A/CoreFP (0x10d804ed0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:41 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPArtworkAgent[33728]: objc[33728]: Class PDFToRasterImageRef is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPLibrary.framework/Versions/A/AMPLibrary and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AMPLibrary.framework/Versions/A/Support/AMPArtworkAgent. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:51 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPDevicesAgent[33726]: getattrlist failed for /Library/GPUBundles/AppleIntelHD5000GraphicsVADriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleIntelHD5000GraphicsVADriver: #2: No such file or directory
Mar  1 16:44:51 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw AMPDevicesAgent[33726]: getattrlist failed for /Library/GPUBundles/AppleIntelHSWVA.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleIntelHSWVA: #2: No such file or directory
Mar  1 16:44:53 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.05000000-0300-0000-0000-000000000000[31602]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[100]
Mar  1 16:44:53 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.0E000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000[31672]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[100]
Mar  1 16:44:54 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.0B000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000[31692]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[100]
Mar  1 16:44:54 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.BKAgentService[33751]: objc[33751]: Class UfDkPx3UB2zY60 is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BookKitFoundation.framework/Versions/A/BookKitFoundation and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BookKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.BKAgentService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.BKAgentService. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:55 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000[33739]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[100]
Mar  1 16:44:55 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.07000000-0300-0000-0000-000000000000[33737]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[100]
Mar  1 16:44:55 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.08000000-0600-0000-0000-000000000000[33738]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[100]
Mar  1 16:44:56 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw Console[32650]: BUG in libdispatch client: vnode, monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked { 0x6000020fa300[source], ident: 12 / 0xc, handler: 0x7fff70b63550 }
Mar  1 16:44:58 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw accountsd[32095]: objc[32095]: Class RMLog is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/RemoteManagement.framework/Versions/A/RemoteManagement (0x7fff8bfd4910) and /System/Library/Accounts/Notification/RemoteManagementAccountsNotificationPlugin.bundle/Contents/MacOS/RemoteManagementAccountsNotificationPlugin (0x111421618). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:59 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw accountsd[32095]: objc[32095]: Class AMSSyncAccountFlagsResult is implemented in both /System/Library/Accounts/Notification/AMSAccountNotificationPlugin.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AMSAccountNotificationPlugin (0x7fff8bfcc968) and /System/Library/Accounts/Authentication/AMSAccountAuthenticationPlugin.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AMSAccountAuthenticationPlugin (0x1114e6d00). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Mar  1 16:44:59 MacBook-Pro-Mirosaw accountsd[32095]: objc[32095]: Class AMSSyncAccountFlagsTask is implemented in both /System/Library/Accounts/Notification/AMSAccountNotificationPlugin.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AMSAccountNotificationPlugin (0x7fff8bfcc9b8) and /System/Library/Accounts/Authentication/AMSAccountAuthenticationPlugin.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AMSAccountAuthenticationPlugin (0x1114e6d50). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Comment: I would look in the console.app for something around the time it happened last. If there is nothing there that would likely indicate that the issue was a "surprise" to macOS as well and possibly related to a hardware issue.

Comment: Definitely get out a paper and pencil. Recording the date / time when this happens - you will quickly get to 10 events and can post more details other than "random" since the timing of this will likely help us help you indeed...

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same problem on Big Sur 11.2.3.

Comment: I've got the same problem. Every app crashes as soon as I click it and won't reopen. This includes Finder and the Menubar. Any help debugging is welcome. I'm at a loss. I followed the instructions and created a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/uDP2yzyc) with the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with I would boot your Mac into Safe Mode and determine if your apps still crash in the same pattern of behaviour.

**Boot into Safe Mode**

Follow these steps to boot your Mac into Safe Mode:

1. Fully shut down your Mac
2. Restart your Mac
3. Immediately press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and **keep it down**
4. Let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window (NOTE: If you have FileVault enabled you may need to log in twice).
5. Take a note of what happens (i.e. do your apps still crash/close every few mins while in Safe Mode)
6. Exit Safe Mode by restarting your Mac as normal
7. Test again to see if your apps still crash/close when booted normally

Once you've tested in Safe Mode, let me know how you went and we'll go from there.

**[UPDATE]**

Now that we've established apps aren't closing/crashing in Safe Mode, we know that your hardware is okay. This means the problem is essentially software related.

I would now check what you have listed in your Login Items. To do this:

1. Go to Apple > System Preferences > Users & Groups
2. Make sure your User Account is selected at top left
3. Click on the Login Items tab
4. Make a note (or take a screenshot) of what items you have listed there
5. Now remove each of the items by clicking on their name (so they're highlighted) and then clicking on the minus <kbd>-</kbd> button
6. Once all items are removed, exit System Preferences
7. Restart your Mac
8. Test to see if the problem still persists
9. If the problem persists, stop here and let me know. If the problem has gone away, continue below
10. Repeat Steps 1 to 3
11. Click on the plus <kbd>+</kbd> button to add **one** of the items back
12. Exit System Preferences
13. Restart your Mac

If the problem returns, repeat Steps 1 to 3 and then remove the item again. If the problem didn't return, start again at Step 10. Continue this process until you identify the item(s) that cause the problem.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help.
It doesn't happen in save mode nor when I use newly created account.
Is there any way to identify what program is causing this? I'm a web dev and switching to new account means copying multiple projects, reinstalling dependencies, adjusting permissions etc. - a lot of work.

Comment: Ok, we're making some headway! :) I've just added an update to my answer with what I'd do next. Let me know how you go.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on my cMP5,1 running Big Sur 11.2.3 with OCLP 0.2.1. I did a complete reinstall and build the system up from scratch. The issue is back. In my case it can take hours before the system crashes. I'm having a hard time debugging. Especially as it's hard to pinpoint the moment the problem starts and logs are completely clogged at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Let's gather some information from `launchd`. Please append your question with (a [PasteBin](https://www.pastebin.com) link to) the output from the following commands which you should run immediately after this happens again (within one minute, otherwise increase `1m` to something longer):

1. `log show --info --debug --last 1m --predicate "(subsystem == 'com.apple.processmanager') || (subsystem == 'com.apple.launchservices')"`
2. `launchctl list | grep -v com.apple`
3. `sudo launchctl list | grep -v com.apple`
4. `launchctl print system | grep -v com.apple`
5. `` sudo launchctl print user/`whoami` | grep -v com.apple ``
6. `kextstat | grep -v com.apple`